# Python asterisk pattern using for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I need to create functions that will print out a certain pattern, using a for loop, when they are called.

```
def patternOne():
    for k in range(numberOfRows):
        for a in range(numberOfRows):
            print("*", end="")
        print()

def patternTwo():
    for k in range(numberOfRows):
        for a in range(k + 1):
            print("*", end="")
        print()

def patternThree():
    for k in range(numberOfRows):
        for a in range(numberOfRows - k):
            print("*", end="")
        print()
```

The last pattern I need should print out a pattern like so:

```
**
* *
*  *
*   *
*    *
```

but I'm confused on how to do so.

Comment: Think about what changes between each line. Do you think you could produce those differences between the lines with a loop?

Comment: So is your question stating that the first three function are what you have now, they work correctly, and you are providing them for reference and the question is how to produce the last pattern?  Or are you saying that patternThree() should produce the patter you have above?

Comment: The first three functions are correct and yes they're just for reference.

Comment: I can't understand your question. You can print your pattern with `print("\n".join(["*" + " "*x + "*" for x in range(4)]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a character `n`-times if you multiply it by `n`. So if you want `n`-spaces, you can do:

```
" " * n
```

Now the problem is to prepend and append a `*`. This is trivial. Here's the code.

```
def patternFoo(numberOfRows):
  for n in range(numberOfRows):
    print("*" + " " * n + "*")

patternFoo(5)
```

Here's the output.

```
15:30 $ python test.py 
**
* *
*  *
*   *
*    *
```